# How to play audio from blob object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, blob

I'm trying to create an audio recorder app using ReactJS. I used the npm package [react-mic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mic) to serve the purpose. But the recordings were saved as a **blob** object.

How to play the recorded file (blob object) in the browser? And how to upload this as an audio file to online storage? (like firebase)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using this: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player`

From the docs:

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return <ReactPlayer url='<--YOUR BLOB -->' playing />
  }
}
```

And a more elaborate example can be found [here](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/blob/master/src/demo/App.js) - not tested though, as I would have to wire your project up. But looking at your blob mime-type, it's webm, which this library supports.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Any idea about how to upload this blob to firebase and stream from there later?

Comment: I haven't used firebase. I use Azure Table Storage my self primarily, but have a look at this: https://medium.com/@puoygae/tutorial-how-to-upload-files-using-firebase-fbe598538c52

The general idea of any table storage is you upload it and it get's a specific URL from which you can then download it again. Usually you specify a container of sorts, and then a filename; firebase_url/container_name/myBlob - when you want to get it again it's just a matter of fetching it and streaming it with the right mime-type.

Comment: can we play audio blob file using this library ? my audio url : blob:http://localhost:3001/92bef7a5-1ce3-47bb-82ae-56ded4a01e4c

Answer (score 6):

The important part is the blobUrl. With it you can create an Audio element. (That is what other libraries do).

For example, in the handleStop() of React Mic, you can set that url in your state :

```
const handleStop = (recordedBlob) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob.blob);
    setSrc(url) //setting the url in your state. A hook in this case btw
  }
```

Then you can create an other function/method in your component and create/play the audio object:

```
const handlePlay = () => {
    const tmp = new Audio(src); //passing your state (hook)
    tmp.play() //simple play of an audio element. 
  }
```

You can also save the audio object in your state... anyway, this is a topic more about javascript/html than react or React-mic

If you want to use a npm library, i could recommend you the [react-h5-audio-player,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-h5-audio-player) it is more friendly.